# Does an empty javascript .push() do anything?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking at some legacy code from another developer and I see this mysterious line:

```
if (hasEmail) {
        fields.push();
}
```

Very confused... I think this line doesn't do anything because the push has no elements being pushed, but before I delete it, I want to know if there is something I don't know, some javascript usage of push I had never considered.

Comment: Tried it and.. ? (`x = ["try","things"]; x.push(); x`) tldr; it's probably just more incorrect code.

Comment: Seems like it'd be faster to try it than write up the question!

Comment: Curiously, the parameter is *not* listed as optional per [MDN Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).. this might lead to the [incorrect] conclusion that it 'might' add `undefined` .. Have to look in the specification I guess *sigh*.

Comment: Per [the ES6 spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.push): "When the push method is called with *zero or more* arguments.. let items be a list whose [*zero or more*] elements are.."  So, MDN documentation could be improved :}

Answer (score 2):

If that's all the code is, yes, it doesn't do anything.

```js
const arr = [];
arr.push();
console.log(arr);
```

Every element passed to `push` is added to the end of the array. If no elements are passed, no elements are added. But, there's one more thing to consider - `push` returns the *new length* of the array. So it would be *theoretically possible* (though quite unlikely in a sane codebase) to see something like

```js
const arr = ['foo', 'bar'];
console.log(arr.push() * arr.push());
```

where the `push` is used to get to get the length of the array, so make sure the expression isn't being used before deleting it.

Although the first argument isn't shown as optional on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), the spec shows that the first argument is indeed optional:

https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.push

> 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
> 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
> 3. Let items be a List whose elements are, in left to right order, the arguments that were passed to this function invocation.
> 4. Let argCount be the number of elements in items.
> 5. If len + argCount > 253-1, throw a TypeError exception.
> 6. Repeat, while items is not empty
>
> a. Remove the first element from items and let E be the value of the element.
>
> b. Perform ? Set(O, ! ToString(len), E, true).
>
> c. Let len be len+1.
>
> 7. Perform ? Set(O, "length", len, true).
> 8. Return len.

When nothing is passed, step 6 just doesn't repeat at all.